# Android GCM/FCM,multiple users application. User and Admin

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-console

Android GCM/FCM,multiple users application

Designing GCM/FCM,multiple users Android application

Trying to design multi user application Admin and normal user

I am confused how should I design the application?

Which way to prefer amongst following or any other best way other than this? 
1. Do I need to create 2 different applications? one for user and one for Admin? 
2. Do I need to populate respective screens according to user who is logging in?
3. Do I need to create one user application and for admin web console? 
Need inputs regarding web console. What technology I should prefer? JavaScript/HTML/AngularJS/PHP?

Comment: Preferably make two seperate apps to prevent any misuse in case someone figures out the admin pass. That should answer 1 and 2. Technology to be used is totally upto you... Use whatever you are comfortable with. I personally use JAVA servlets, jsp, html and javascript but that's just me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an ADMIN user named into one app runs the risk of someone figuring out the way to reach the admin screens.

To avoid that, the best practise is to make two apps. One for the regular people and one for the admin.

As for the web technology part, that's totally your choice. Use what you are comfortable with. Optimisations can come later when you master your choice. All the tech you've mentioned is very capable and very good.

I personally use Servlets, JSP, HTML  and javascript with mysql. This will always vary from developer to developer.

Also avoid such broad questions on stack, it will earn you a lot of negative reputation.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. And thanks for the suggestion regarding reputation. :)